# Docker container port unreachable Spring Boot App

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I run my application in my host.

```
java -jar docker-spring-boot.war


 http://localhost:8083/
```

On the browser, it works fine.

In the docker container, it didn't work.

```
 docker run docker-spring-boot -p 8083:8083

 http://localhost:8083/
 http://192.168.99.100:8083/
```

I have this message:

`This site is inaccessible`

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8083
ADD target/docker-spring-boot.war docker-spring-boot.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/docker-spring-boot.war"]
```

Have you an idea about the solution ?

Comment: How come you run `-jar file.war`?

Comment: java -jar docker-spring-boot.war

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)

Comment: Have you checked the docker logs of that container? Any errors in them?